# How do I implement object picking, using OBB in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, raytracing, 3d

I am trying to make 3D drawing software. I wanted to have the drag feature so I am using object picking using the OBB algorithm. I am facing problems in understanding the algorithm, and my implementation thus is having bugs.

How do I implement object picking, using OBB in OpenGL? As I am new to OpenGL (free-glut library), a step by step explanation would be helpful.

I am not able to understand what t1 and t2 mean and how the algorithm is working. If you explain the algorithm that would be enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problems? Also just to be sure, this doesn't have anything directly to do with OpenGL right?

Comment: I am facing problem in implementing object picking using obb algorithm.I am not able to understand what does t1 and t2 means and how the algorithm is working. And for opengl i am using glut library if you explain the algorithm that would be enough.

Comment: First of go with GLFW library rather than going with freeglut And check out this tutorial... http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

Comment: @dkoder Can you edit the question to summarize what you understand already and where specifically you're having trouble? Currently your question is too unclear to really answer. :(

Answer (score 3):

Ray vs OBB intersection works by shooting a ray towards the OBB's planes. This results in 2 intersections referred to as `t1` and `t2` (per axis), also referred to as `tNear` and `tFar` or `tMin` and `tMax`.

[image]

Checking whether the ray intersects with the box, can then be done by comparing the largest `tNear` against the smallest `tFar`. If the largest `tNear` is less than the smallest `tFar` then there is a intersection.

Comment: thanks for this i just have couple of questions....first what are the equations of this plane and for 3d i should have a pair of z planes right?

Comment: Yes for 3D you'd just have to add z as well, the concept stays the same. I can write you a short snippet of the algorithm. Do you have a preferred language? C, Python or?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...python code would be nice